# The repo for the "server for Pakistan" is outdated where I report it?

Tags: repository

I've been encountering this problem for years. I keep having to switch to the Main Server because the one for Pakistan is too outdated to even complete an `apt-get update`

Where is the right place to report this?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us

Comment: Main server is better for indian sub continent since Main server is faster than other server in the sub continent

Comment: Yes, but that's just a workaround. Also, following the contact page more or less leads to launchpad.. I suppose I'll just post a question there.

Comment: [Launchpad](http://bugs.launchpad.net) is official site for filing bugs regarding Ubuntu.

Comment: It is not a bug,  just that the respective server owner does not care too much of updating the repositories. You should look for some other server. The main server works pretty well in the subcontinent(I'm in India, and I use the main server)

Comment: @RegisteredUser default country mirror pointing to some outdated mirror instead of pointing to Main is a bug in my opinion. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [country mirror requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors#Country_mirror_requirements) that unfortunately are still not being followed in Pakistan. You can report these violations by sending an email to `mirrors@ubuntu.com`. I did that last year and they disabled default pk mirror `pk.archive.ubuntu.com` pointer to outdated Nayatel's Mirror. Check this (Email screenshot with their response): https://askubuntu.com/a/1116886/140778

Answer (score 3):

The repositories of Ubuntu are owned by third parties and hence it is their responsibility to update the servers on time.

As the server you are using is not always updated, you should consider using other servers. The main server works very well in the Indian subcontinent. Otherwise you may use the [Nayatel pvt. ltd](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirrors.nayatel.com-archive) server which is located in Pakistan.

There would be no use of reporting this as a bug on launchpad, as it is not a bug. You may contact the repo owner if you wish.

Comment: But since the repo comes bundled in Ubuntu and is automatically selected when installing, would it not qualify as a bug? At the very least a UX bug?

Comment: @amingilani At the most you can file it as a "feature request" that Ubuntu should check repo update status before selecting it. But it is not a bug.  A bug is something which is implemented but does not work as expected. here the feature you might want is neither implemented and (obviously) not expected. This is why it is not a bug.